# How to make thread wait in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_of_pages) as executor:
            futh = [(executor.submit(self.getdata2, page, hed, data, apifolder,additional)) for page in pages]
            for data in as_completed(futh):
                datarALL = datarALL + data.result()
        return datarALL
```

The `num_of_pages` isn't fixed but usualy it's around 250.
`getdata2` func creates GET requests and return each page results:

The problem is that all 250 pages (threads) are created together. which means 250 GET requests which are called at the same time. This cause overload in the server so I get alot of retries due to delayed server response which shuts down the GET call and retry it. I want to avoid it.

I thought of creating some sort of lock which will prevent the thread/page from creating the GET request if there are more than 10 active requests. In such case it will wait till a slot is available.

Some thing like:

```
executing_now = []
def getdata2(...)
    ...
    while len(executing_now)>10:
       sleep(10)
    executing_now.append(page)
    response = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
    ....
    executing_now.remove(page)
    return ...
```

Is there an existed mechanism for this in Python? This requires the threads to check for a shared memory... I want to avoid the multi threading problems such as deadlock etc..

Basically warp the GET call with a limit of how many threads can execute it on the same time.

Comment: Are you aware of the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) in most implementations of Python ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes but it doesn't matter here. My issue is when GET is called and then there is context switch to another thread. I want to narrow this possibility allowing only 10 threads to be executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `queue` to "prepare" all your pages, and then you can limit to your thread pool to any number of threads since each thread will fetch needed page from queue:

```
# preparing here all you page objects
pages_queue = queue.Queue()
[pages_queue.put(page) for page in pages]

# ThreadPool - Each thread will take one page from queue, and when done, will fetch next one
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    futh = [(executor.submit(self.getdata2, pages_queue, hed, data, apifolder,additional))]
    for data in as_completed(futh):
        datarALL = datarALL + data.result()
return datarALL

def getdata2(...)
    ...
    try:
       while True: # non blocking wait will raise Empty when queue is empty
          page = pages_queue.get_nowait()
          response = requests.get(page.url, data=data, headers=hed, verify=False)
          ....
          return ...
    except queue.Empty:
       pass
```

Comment: Thank you. actually your answer helped me to find a much simpler solution... The max_workers=num_of_pages was wrong. changing it to cpu_count() solved my issue.. Only 4 threads are created at each time. When one finished another is created.